# Table with extra column

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting 2 simple tables but an extra column keeps appearing on both. I checked that my data has only 3 columns and so is the colLabel.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

header= ['Country','HDI','IPV']

header_colors1 = ['#03a1fc', '#03a1fc', '#03a1fc']

row_colors1 = ['#f1f1f2', 'w'] * 10

header_colors2 = ['#dd8452', '#dd8452', '#dd8452']

row_colors2 = ['w', '#f1f1f2'] * 10

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
fig.patch.set_visible(False)

axs[0].axis('off')
axs[0].axis('tight')

least_dev_values = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
most_dev_values = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
least_dev_tabel= axs[0].table(cellText=least_dev_values, colLabels=header, loc='center',
         cellLoc='center', colLoc='center', rowColours=row_colors1,
         colColours=header_colors1)

axs[1].axis('off')
axs[1].axis('tight')
axs[1].table(cellText=most_dev_values, colLabels=header, loc='center',
         cellLoc='center', colLoc='center', rowColours=row_colors2,
         colColours=header_colors2)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the rowColours it works as expected

```
least_dev_tabel= axs[0].table(cellText=least_dev_values, colLabels=header, loc='center',
         cellLoc='center', colLoc='center', #rowColours=row_colors1,
         colColours=header_colors1)
```

It looks like you might want to add more columns to the table based on your headers? The docs say that these are the colors of your header rows. If you want to color your cells you can use `cellClours` instead

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/table_api.html